# Issue with chrome extension code to fetch tweets from twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension which shows tweets with hashtag `perkytweets` in the extension pop up but nothing is showing up.

Here is the manifest.json code

```
    {
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Here is the popup.html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width:357px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin:5px;
        border:2px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
      }
    </style>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the script.js code

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
    "GET",
    "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=perkytweets",
    true);
req.onload = showTweets;
req.send(null);


function showTweets()
{
    document.body.appendChild(req.responseXML);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fire of the request only when the document has been loaded. try wrapping your code in an `onload` handler

```
function showTweets() {
    document.body.appendChild(req.responseXML);
}

var req;
window.onload = function() {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=perkytweets", true);
    req.onload = showTweets;
    req.send(null);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You need to allow access to the twitter URL, add this to your manifest:

```
"permissions": [ "http://search.twitter.com/*" ]
```

So your `manifest.json` will now look like this:

```
{
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "http://search.twitter.com/*"
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

`req.responseXML` is not an Element yet, and as such cannot be directly appended to the body, `console.log` your result and go from there.

Comment: open up the inspector for your extension, what does the chrome log say?

Comment: Its giving error       XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=perkytweets. Origin chrome-extension://cbphocgfcalbcgcndefolpdljmapgnim is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: ok, now we are going somewhere, you need to allow access to that url in your manifest, ill update the answer now

Comment: ok i just gave permissions in the manifest file but now some new error.....Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3 script.js:14